# Constraints of text that is showing in asp.net Label's

Tags: asp.net, label

everyone!
Could someone tall me how I can limit count of line of text, that is showing in asp.net Label control?
Thanks!

Comment: Why you need to limit the linecount instead of limiting the size(width,height) of the label?

Comment: This way doesn't work if Length of text is beegest as labels size and then its size is ignorizing.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this css to define a max width for the cell(or the outer container). To define a max length of the text, you have to truncate the text to your maximum length by yourself.

```
.longtext td{ width:100px;word-wrap : break-word ;word-break : normal; }
<asp:Label ID="lblText" runat="server" CssClass="longtext">

lblText.Text=lblText.substring(0,yourMaxLength)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make changes .css

```
.limitWidth {

    white-space: nowrap;     
    max-width: 100px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow-x: hidden;

}
```